# DbConfiguration instance used before 'EFConfiguration' type was discovered

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my MVC4 application I am having reference to my EF model assembly.  Everything was working fine.  All of a sudden I started getting below error message.

```
The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'EFConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of 'EFConfiguration' must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.
```

I am using EF 6.  Any idea what could be the reason?  I double check with database and its updated and in sync with EF dll.

Update: I am getting this error when I am trying to instantiate Context object

```
mEntities context = new Entities();
```

Thanks

Comment: where are you trying to instantiate the Context?

Comment: In my MVC4 website.  I have an assembly EF.DLL which has all the EntityFramework related artifacts including DbContext class and I am referring this assembly in my MVC4 webapplication.

Comment: could you add your context declaration and the call to it from Global.asax?

Comment: Thanks, problem was something else.  It was wrong version of MVC framework dll.  The error message was misleading but that is developer's life :)

Answer (score 4):

I just want to leave a solution for those having similar error message. As [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699) from Vinicius Paiva, it clearly explains that if you have multiple dbcontex in different dlls, you should reference to your DbConfiguration file if you created one in your code. 
in my case I had azure functions project referencing on DAL project and only way to get azure functions project is to create partial class and code based DbConfiguration file.

So extending my edmx file DbContext with code below

```
namespace myApp.Data.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(myDBContextConfig))]
    partial class myDBEntities
    {

        public myDBEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }

      public  class myDBContextConfig : DbConfiguration
        {
            public myDBContextConfig()
            {
                SetProviderServices("System.Data.EntityClient", 
                SqlProviderServices.Instance);
                SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
            }
        }
    }
```

This DAL library was referencing on an MVC project where we had another edmx instance. So when I run on this project, it was throwing this exception. In order to fix this. you need to extend or add entityFramework node as below in your config file (web.config in this case)

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="myApp.Data.Models.myDBContextConfig , myApp.Data">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

May your problem is because you have a class like this sample in you're DAL

```
public class EfConfiguration : DbConfiguration
```

In this case you must initialise this before using EF Context in the Global.asax

Rgds

Comment: This could be happening because you have more than one project using EntityFramework, so entity framework has some internal classes that are instantiated globally. You need to tell EntityFramework in advance (before creating your DBContext) about your DbConfigurations. In my case I had 3 projects using EF (2 MsSql, 1 Oracle). The oracle requires a different DbConfiguration. You need to use this DbConfiguration on your OracleDbContext and set the following line in your application startup to tell EF: DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new OracleDbConfiguration());

Comment: The error has a link to a microsoft page, take some time and read it carefully you will find the answer. Good luck! 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699